# IIS express serves one .asmx service, but always returns 404 on another

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asmx, iis-express

I upgraded an old solution to Visual Studio 2015, and ran into trouble with one of the .asmx web services. I have a number of them in this solution, and IIS express loads and runs them all correctly, except one. This one service always returns a 404 if I try to load the .asmx URL in IIS express. It runs correctly in full-blown IIS.

None of the problems I've found online solve my situation. Here are the details:

1. The web.config files of the working and non-working web services are identical.
2. The IIS express/.csproj configuration is identical, except for the port and project names, and a few different assembly references.
3. The projects are virtually identical as well, with only a single .asmx service file with a code behind .asmx.cs and .asmx.resx files.
4. The C:\Users[my username]\IIS Express\config\applicationhost.config doesn't list any of the working or non-working services, so that can't be the difference.
5. Examining the complete trace from C:\Users[my username]\IIS Express\TraceLogFiles[service]\fr000040.xml  for a request on working and non-working services, they are virtually identical right up to step 109, AspNetMapHandlerEnter. The working service goes right to AspNetMapHandlerLeave at step 110, where the non-working service sets a few cache headers and then at step 112 sets the status code to 404 with a "warning" label on it.

I'm not sure what's going on here or what I can do next, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I normally only copy over the bin file during deployment and then my ashx / asmx doesn't load since the files do not exist on the server so check to make sure the place holder file exists. Just a thought since I run into that.

Comment: 2 is suspicious. You have to show more about the differences you mentioned in this spot so that we can see how they differ from each other.

Comment: The working service doesn't have the .asmx marked as "do not copy", so that's what I set for the non-working one as well. Telling it to copy still doesn't work though.

Comment: re: 2 and the .csproj differences, I'm not sure what you expect to see. The working service uses log4net the non-working one doesn't. The latter also includes a few reporting dlls as well, and System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq. Then the ports are different, and that's literally all that differs. Like I said, this all works fine on full-blown IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by basically creating a new project and importing all the old files. IIS express must have cached something somewhere when the project was invalid, and by recreating the assembly information it forced a refresh.